# Optional in text view showing when printing

Tags: swift, text, option-type, unwrap

Hi all I have tried a few solutions but no luck.

I am getting the text from Data Core, but the textview has optional on it.

when it prints it shows optional in the text.

```
page22TextView?.text = ("\(trans.value(forKey: "page22"))")
```

can anyone shed light on this ! have tried to unwrap but it stillelow: shows.

the full function is below:

```
func getTranscriptions () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()


    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        //I like to check the size of the returned results!
        print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")

        //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
        for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {


            page22TextView?.text = ("\(trans.value(forKey: "page22"))")
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
            print("\(trans.value(forKey: "page22"))")

        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with **if-let** statement:

```
if let result = trans.value(forKey: "page22") {

    page22TextView?.text = result
}
```

Or try with **guard** statement:

```
guard let result = trans.value(forKey: "page22") else { return }
page22TextView?.text = String(describing: result)
```

Or you can **force upwrap** it like:

```
let result = trans.value(forKey: "page22")

if result != nil {

    page22TextView?.text = result! as! String
}
```

Or you can follow the way suggested by @MrugeshTank below in answers

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, with the first one i get back the yellow triangle that says: Nom-optional expression of type 'String' used in a check for optionals.  The second one i get an ! error on the  = result, saying Cannot assign value of Any to a type string, I tried to add  as! String on the end, the third one how ever I got the same error as above but this time when I added the as! String at the end of result it worked, Thank you for that and the different options i can learn about. this was a great help

Comment: Thanks again for that.

Answer (score 1):

try to set default value of getting nil value

```
page22TextView?.text = (trans.value(forKey: "page22") as? String) ?? ""
```

It'll set your value from `trans` and if it retrun `nill` will be set by `""`.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help, With this i get the yellow triangle that says, "Left side of nil coalescing operator ?? has non-optional type String, so the right side was never used. the result on compile is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

try to unwrap optional using **if let** then assign to your textview (if necessary then downcast your value)

```
if let value = trans.value(forKey: "page22") {
   page22TextView?.text = value
}
```

or

```
use guard for unwrap
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help, I tried the first part of this and got the same result, I am new to this about 7 months in training and haven't used guard that much so not to sure how to use it in this